# Detect NUL file descriptor (isatty is bogus)

Tags: c, windows, terminal

The following C file gives a bogus result when NUL is piped to it:

```
int main()
{
  printf("_isatty = %d\n", _isatty(0));
}
```

the result is:

```
C:\Users\Edward\Dev\nulltest> test.exe < NUL
_isatty = 64
```

I'm pretty sure NUL (aka /dev/null) is not a terminal device! So I need to detect in another way whether or not the file descriptor corresponds to NUL. The number doesn't have any specific meaning; I see it when I actually do have a terminal attached.

What should I do? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926865/isatty-on-windows-ce) suggests using a sketchy undocumented function to get the underlying name, presumably comparing it to NUL, but that feels less than ideal to me. Is there a better way?

P.S. This would help solve [this GHC bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2628).

Comment: Just out of interest (and I'm not saying that what you're doing is wrong): why do you care where the input's coming from?

Comment: There are many applications which do different things when they detect a terminal. For example, if you type 'python', it will go into interactive mode, but 'echo "print \"bar\"" | python' will not show any of the initialization screen.

Comment: Well, in this case, I'm only debugging this because it's causing the testsuite to fail and I hate a failing testsuite :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> _isatty returns a nonzero value if the descriptor is associated with a
>   character device. Otherwise, _isatty
>   returns 0.

NUL is like /dev/null on Unix, it's a char device.

Note that on Linux, isatty is different:

> The isatty() function tests whether fd
>   is an open file descriptor referring
>   to a terminal.

What you can do is try to compare STDIN_FILENO (0) with ${cwd}/NUL (using stat or stat).

**Update:**

```
int ret = GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
```

It will return FILE_TYPE_CHAR for NUL or tty.

See [GetFileType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364960%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation for other values. You can detect files/char device/pipes.

**Update Final:**

Use [GetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for input and [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171%28VS.85%29.aspx) for output.

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi;
DWORD mode;
if (!GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &mode))
   fprintf(stderr, "not console\n");
else
   fprintf(stderr, "console\n");
if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &sbi))
   fprintf(stderr, "not console\n");
else
  fprintf(stderr, "console\n");
```

Comment: Interesting! That implies that we should not actually be using isatty to detect if there is a terminal. Is there equivalent functionality available on Windows?

Comment: _isatty is bugged, it should detect if you're using a terminal, not if the fd is a character device. I'm not sure what's the best way to do it on windows. You can try to check cygwin/mingway isatty implementation. You can also create a wrapper blacklisting $(CWD)/NUL, as it's probably the only character device you'll easily use on windows.

Comment: But... that doesn't distinguish between NUL or tty. (I'm slightly confused.)

Comment: Hum right .. I think I lost the real question .. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, but I'm not convinced it works all the time. I believe it will work for the specific case of a NUL file descriptor:

```
int real_isatty(int fd) {
    DWORD st;
    HANDLE h;
    if (!_isatty(fd)) {
        /* TTY must be a character device */
        return 0;
    }
    h = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        /* Broken handle can't be terminal */
        return 0;
    }
    if (!GetConsoleMode(h, &st)) {
        /* GetConsoleMode appears to fail when it's not a TTY. */
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `fstat` on the file descriptor and compare the device member of the resulting `stat` structure with that for `/dev/null` and see if they match.

Comment: Doesn't work. _stat invariably returns 2, while _fstat invariably returns 0.