# Is there a way to determine in C++ whether Mac stdout is pointing to the console?

Tags: c++, macos

A while ago, I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972071/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-stdout-is-pointing-to-the-console) how I could determine, from a C++ program running on **Windows**, whether stdout was pointing to the console. I received a useful answer: GetConsoleMode().

*UPDATE: To be specific, this expression evaluates as true if stdout points to the console:*

```
GetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &temp)
```

Now I'm trying to solve the same problem on **Mac**. Is there a similar function that I can call from Mac OS X to determine whether stdout is pointing to the console?

*UPDATE: People have suggested using the function isatty(), which takes a file descriptor. In the Windows case, that descriptor was obtained by calling GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE). I will check out whether I can call `isatty(fileno(stdout))`, as suggested.*

Comment: Do you know [isatty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)? That function should be a portable solution to your problem