# How to tell if stderr has been redirected in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, console

I want my program to have different behaviors between when stderr is connected to a console and when it is redirected to a file/pipe. In Unix systems I can just test `isatty(STDERR_FILENO)`, but how do I do that in Windows? MSVCRT also has a function named `_isatty`, it doesn't function properly (for example, [Detect NUL file descriptor (isatty is bogus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648711/detect-nul-file-descriptor-isatty-is-bogus)). Is there any Windows or NT API I can call to test it?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Which do you use?

Comment: @Olaf: It doesn't matter. The Windows API can be consumed from both C and C++. It is standard practice to ask for a solution in C or C++ (which doesn't make a difference).

Comment: @IInspectable: If that is a matter of the WinAPI, it uses C binding, thus it is a C question.

Comment: The [accepted answer from the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648711/detect-nul-file-descriptor-isatty-is-bogus#3650507) has the solution, except you need to use `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` instead of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Call `GetStdHandle` to get the stderr handle.
2. Pass that handle to `GetFileType` to find out what type of file it is.
3. If that returns `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` then stderr could be a console, but call `GetConsoleMode` to check.
4. If `GetConsoleMode` fails then stderr has been redirected to another character device, such as a printer.

Comment: This is not enough, as explained in the [proposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40709193/1889329).

Comment: Will `GetConsoleMode` ever succeeds if the handle is not a character device? If not, then the `GetFileType` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simplest approach was to use `fseek(stderr, 0, SEEK_CUR)` which returns `0` if the `stderr` is redirected to a file and `<>0` if `stderr` is not redirected.